# Turning off debug mode in production

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Working as a summer intern for a smaller company and the other devs are on vacation so I'm in charge of publishing our changes. I just published to our stage server but I can see that no redirects are happening. I found in our redirects file that we have a condition like this:

```
#if DEBUG
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug mode");
#else
     // here goes all our redirect code
#endif
```

So, I'm guessing our redirect problem is caused by my solution that is published in some way is staying in debug mode. Hopefully this is a quick fix -- is there something I could do? If not, I'll just remove the if condition and go with the redirect code, but I don't like the idea of removing the code that was intended to be here by our other developers.

Comment: How did you compile your solution? In Release or Debug mode?

Comment: I would say this is terrible coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DEGUB`-variable is set by default from Visual Studio when compiling for "debug". This is what you see on project --> properties --> build. In the upper area there´s a configuration-textbox where the actual build-configuration is shown:

[image]

As you can see in the imagine you can also deactivate the setting for that variable, even when chosing debug-level as build-configuration but I can´t imagine why anyone would do this. Seems like a debug-light, where we print only some debug-statements, but not all. On the other side you could define the constant also in release-mode.

Apart from this making a switch on that variable *and* printing a debug-message is quite overkill, as `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug mode");` will show the message on debug level only, anyway.

In production on the other side you should compile for release-mode by chosing another build-configuration.

Comment: You can also define `DEBUG`when compiling in Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx):

> To change the build configuration
>
> 1. From the Build menu: click Build / Configuration Manager, then select Debug or Release.
> 2. On the toolbar, choose either Debug or Release from the Solution Configurations list box

[image]

This toolbar is not available in Express editions. You can use the Build Solution F6 and Start Debugging F5 menu items to choose the configuration.